# Getting Netflix catalogs' of other countries

Tags: netflix

Using my Netflix dev key with node.js and nodeflix, I've been able to retrieve the catalogs for the US (/catalog/titles/streaming) and Canada (/catalog/titles/streaming/en_CA.xml). However, I've been unable to find any information on how to get the catalogs for other countries.  I picked the UK as a test and tried a couple of dozen permutations on the country code (e.g. '/catalog/titles/streaming/en_GB.xml', '/catalog/titles/streaming/en-GB.xml', etc.) both outside the UK, and via a VPN from inside the UK. None of these worked.  I know this is possible as other sites have this information. There's no information on Netflix's (now disabled) forums and api docs and they now re-direct all questions here. Does anyone know what the urls are?

Answer (score 0):

I did some tests, and only US and CA are supported.

Its a pitty, they dont extend api to other countries